# jQuery button effects overriding

Tags: jquery

Basically I have made a light bulb and there are 2 switches. The first one turns it on and the other one off. Also I have slider to adjust opacity of the light. The main issue that I am experiencing is that, when the bulb is turned off opacity turns to value 0, however after adjusting via slider opacity it automatically turns on. So I am trying to figure out how can I disable this.

Currently my jQuery code looks like this:

```js
$('#switchOn').on('click', function() {
  $('#contrast').on('input', function() {
    $('#light').css('opacity', $(this).val());
  });
});

$('#switchOff').on('click', function() {
  $('#light').css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Basically `id=contrast` is the id and value of the slider, `id=switchOn` is button to turn it on, `id=switchOff` to turn it off. `Id=light` is my light source, which  is basically a circle made using SVG.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding a new event every time you switch on, I would change your code to be

```js
var $light = $('#light');
var $contrast = $('#contrast');

$contrast.on('input', function() {            // bind this separately or remove this fully if you don't want the slider to do anything
  $light.css('opacity', $(this).val());
});

$('#switchOn').on('click', function() {
  $light.css('opacity', $contrast.val());     // use the contrast value when you switch on
});

$('#switchOff').on('click', function() {
 $light.css('opacity', '0');
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. This certainly helped me. I have used your suggest code fragment and also added variable that indicates whether light is turned on or off, also I have put $light.css('opacity', $(this).val()); under if statement to only execute it when light is on and that worked. Cheers, Pete!